# MongoDB selection with existing value

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, database, nosql

I'm using [PyMongo](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/) to fetch data from [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/). All documents in the collection look like the structure below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50755d055a953d6e7b1699b6"), 
    "actor":
    {
        "languages": ["nl"]
    },
    "language":
    {
        "value": "nl"
    }
}
```

I'm trying to fetch all the conversations where the property `language.value` is inside the property `actor.languages`.

At the moment I know how to look for all conversations with a constant value inside  `actor.languages` (eg. all conversations with *en* inside `actor.languages`).

But I'm stuck on how to do the same comparison with a variable value (`language.value`) inside the current document.

Any help is welcome, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.testcoll.find({$where:"this.actor.languages.indexOf(this.language.value) >= 0"})
```

Comment: I had to add `'actor.languages': {'$exists': True}` and `'language': {'$exists': True}` because not all the documents have the same structure. Thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `$where` provided your query set is small, but any real size and you could start seeing problems, especially since this query seems like one that needs to be run in realtime on a page and the JS engine is single threaded among other problems.

I would actually consider a better way in this case is through the client side, it is quite straight forward, pull out records based on one of the values, iterate and test their conditional double value (i.e. pull out based on `language.value` being nl and test `actor.languages` value for that previous value).

I would imagine you might be able to do this with the aggregation framework however, at the min you cannot use computed fields within `$match`. I would imagine it would look like this:

```
{$project: 
     {languages_value: "$language.value", languages: "$actor.languages"}
}, {$match: {"$languages": {$in:"$languages_values"}}
```

If you could. But there might be a way.

Comment: At the moment we have about 1200000 documents in our database, I think a 'where' will do the job for now. Didn't know about the Aggregation Framework, checking it out right now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Voles A `$where` will never do 1.2m documents in a good amount of time, it slows down a query by upto 10x and people have seen around 67k documents per sec while using it and since it does not use indexes it will scan all 1.2m or all where those fields exist now that you have add the $exists clause. However if you find it does work then stick with it :)

Comment: It works for now, but it doesn't feel good to use `$where`. I'll take your suggestion(s) into account and implement them if the system is getting slow. Thanks again!